# How to install Microsoft silverlight on Ubuntu with wine

Tags: software-installation, wine, microsoft

i want to install Microsoft silverlight on ubuntu is there an way for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pipelight/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends pipelight-multi
sudo pipelight-plugin --update
pipelight-plugin --enable silverlight
```

Silverlight will work in Firefox.

It is actually installation using wine, but it will work in normal browser, not under wine.

Answer (score 0):

If this does not work yet: Additionally to @Pilot6 answer, I had to execute the following command to make in work in Firefox:

```
sudo pipelight-plugin --create-mozilla-plugins
```

And by the way, Firefox disabled Silverlight as of [version 52](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/52.0/releasenotes/).